# How to create a OR statement in one query?

Tags: php, mysql

How do i make a OR query for something like this?

```
//Query
$sql = "select `Friend_status` from `friendship_box` where 
`system_id` = '$sid' and `friend_id` = '$friendis' OR 
`system_id='$friendis' and `friend_id` = '$sid'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$activity = htmlspecialchars($row['Friend_status']);
}
mysql_free_result($query);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select `Friend_status` from `friendship_box` 
where (`system_id` = '$sid' and `friend_id` = '$friendis')
OR (`system_id`='$friendis' and `friend_id` = '$sid')
```

you missed the `` ` `` here:

```
...OR (`system_id` <--
```

Comment: Hey, i tried that before i posted here but it gave me this error: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'friend_id` = '32434')' at line 1

Comment: Geez!! I can't believe i missed that.  Amateur problem!